# Import C dll in C# StringBuilder struct in struct

Tags: c#, c, marshalling, stringbuilder

I need import one function GDPI for C dll and I want to use in one C# application.
My problem is that one parameter is one struct CFSPI and in this struct I have others struct:
PII PPI LPPCC LPPOL LPPOP

My problem is with LPPOL the orignal struct is C is

```
typedef struct tagCFS_PRINT_OVLINFO {
DWORD dwOverlayType;
TCHAR szFormPath[MAX_PATH];
DWORD dwFormID;
BOOL bFormIdFixed;
} CFS_PRINT_OVLINFO, *LPCFS_PRINT_OVLINFO;
```

CFSPI struct is :

```
typedef struct tagCFS_PRINTINFO {
DWORD wCopies;
DWORD dwPrintInterval;
DWORD dwPrintSpeed;
DWORD dwPageID;
DWORD dwJobID;
CFS_PRINT_IMGINFO pii;
CFS_PRINT_PAPERINFO ppi;
LPCFS_PRINT_CCORRECTINFO lppcc;
LPCFS_PRINT_OVLINFO lppol;
LPCFS_PRINT_OPTION lppop;
LPVOID lpReserve1;
LPVOID lpReserve2;
DWORD dwReserve1;
DWORD dwReserve2;
} CFS_PRINTINFO, *LPCFS_PRINTINFO;
```

And function define is

```
int CFTGetDefaultPrintInfo(
IN LPTSTR lptPrinterName, // Printer name to obtain the print information
OUT CFSPI* lpPrtInfo // Default print information
);
```

I try define in C# by

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
internal static extern int CFTGetDefaultPrintInfo(string lptPrinterName, CFSPI lpPrtInfo);

internal struct CFS_PRINTINFO
{
    internal uint dwCopies;
    internal uint dwPrintInterval;
    internal uint dwPrintSpeed;
    internal uint dwPageID;
    internal uint dwJobID;
    internal CFS_PRINT_IMGINFO pii;
    internal CFS_PRINT_PAPERINFO ppi;
    internal CFS_PRINT_CCORRECTINFO lppcc;
    internal CFS_PRINT_OVLINFO lppol;
    internal CFS_PRINT_OPTION lppop; 
    internal IntPtr lpReserve1; 
    internal IntPtr lpReserve2;
    internal uint dwReserve1;
    internal uint dwReserve2;
}

internal struct CFS_PRINT_OVLINFO
{
    internal uint dwOverlayType; // Overlay, Print type
    internal StringBuilder szFormPath; // Form file path
    internal uint dwFormID; // Form file ID
    internal bool bFormIdFixed; // Wether to fix the form ID
}
```

When I call the function I have

> Blockquote Impossible de marshaler le champ 'lppol' de type 'App.CFS_PRINTINFO' : La définition de type de ce champ possède des informations de disposition, mais elle présente une combinaison de types managés/non managés non valide ou elle ne peut pas être marshalée.

I try use string but unsuccessful..

Do you have some idea?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried adding a MarshalAs attribute on the StringBuilder?

Comment: Just use MarshalAsAttribute and declare that field as Char[] szFormPath (or Byte if  ASCII or UTF-8). BTW I'd add StructLayout or FieldOffset to your structures!

Comment: When i change 
     internal StringBuilder szFormPath; // Form file path
by 
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)] 
     internal string szFormPath; // Form file path

I have one other problem that is PInvokeStackInBalance


Do you know how I could find the variable which have the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a fixed buffer, you don't use `StringBuilder`.

```
internal unsafe struct CFS_PRINT_OVLINFO
{
    internal uint dwOverlayType; // Overlay, Print type
    internal fixed char szFormPath[MAX_PATH]; // Form file path
    internal uint dwFormID; // Form file ID
    internal bool bFormIdFixed; // Wether to fix the form ID
}
```

You'll have to enable unsafe code, in order for this to work.

But there are more incompatibilities between the C code, and what you created in C#:
`lppcc`, `lppol` and `lppop` are pointers, so they should be created as pointers, or as `IntPtr`:

```
internal unsafe struct CFS_PRINTINFO
{
    internal uint dwCopies;
    internal uint dwPrintInterval;
    internal uint dwPrintSpeed;
    internal uint dwPageID;
    internal uint dwJobID;
    internal CFS_PRINT_IMGINFO pii;
    internal CFS_PRINT_PAPERINFO ppi;
    internal CFS_PRINT_CCORRECTINFO* lppcc;
    internal CFS_PRINT_OVLINFO* lppol;
    internal CFS_PRINT_OPTION* lppop; 
    internal IntPtr lpReserve1; 
    internal IntPtr lpReserve2;
    internal uint dwReserve1;
    internal uint dwReserve2;
}
```

And even the extern method is defined incorrectly, and should be (assuming `CFSPI` is `CFS_PRINTINFO`):

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
internal static extern int CFTGetDefaultPrintInfo(string lptPrinterName, out CFSPI lpPrtInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much with out it is ok.